# MySQL and PHP advanced product sales: check multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to properly explain, I'll try here.

I have 4 tables:

- `products(id, season_id(FK), year(4), brand_id(FK), price, ...)`
- `seasons(id, name)`
- `brands(id, name)`
- `sales(id, season_id(FK), year(4), brand_id(FK), value(INT))`

As you already guessed `season_id` and `brand_id` are FK where there is `_id`.

Now, depending on the `sales` table, products will have a price that will be calculated. My problem is that there can be any combinations of the `sales` table to calculate the price.

I'll quickly make an example to be clearer.

Table `products` rows:

- `id: 1`, `season_id: 3`, `year: 2013`, `brand_id 3`, `price: 100.00`
- `id: 2`, `season_id: 3`, `year: 2015`, `brand_id 4`, `price: 100.00`
- `id: 3`, `season_id: 4`, `year: 2014`, `brand_id 5`, `price: 100.00`
- `id: 4`, `season_id: 5`, `year: 2014`, `brand_id 5`, `price: 100.00`

Table `sale` rows:

- `season_id: 3`, `year: 2013`, `brand_id: 3`, `value: 5%`
- `season_id: 3`, `year: 2014`, `brand_id: null`, `value: 10%`
- `season_id: 4`, `year: 2015`, `brand_id: null`, `value: 15%`
- `season_id: null`, `year: null`, `brand_id: 5`, `value: 20%`

(all fields are optional, but if there is a season there must be a year)

Given that example

- first product's price will be 100 - 5% ( season 3 + 2013 + brand 3 )
- second product's price will be 100 ( matches season but not year )
- third product's price will be 100 ( matches season but not year )
- fourth product's price will be 100 - 20% (any season + any year + brand 5)

So to wrap up, I need a way to know for each product what sale to apply. The priority is:

```
SeasonYearBrand > SeasonYear > Season > Year > Brand
```

Now I have a query that fetches all products and another one for all sales. Inside a `foreach` I loop through all products and here again another `foreach` where I loop through all sales and finally I check what sale to apply.

I know is very confusing but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it. Each page has 25 products and I have 20 rows in the `sales` table so you can see how easily things get heavy.

Comment: Why not activate it on demand via ajax , otherwise your querying time is going to the roof right ?

Comment: Why isn't product 3 reduced by 20%? The 20% sales record is for brand 5 and any season and year, isn't it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, that was my mistake. Also the real code has 2 more fields in the sales table, I only wrote 3 here for simplicity. My problem is calculating in PHP which sale value to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SQL. Use a subquery to get the best matching sales record. Candiadates are all sales records where the three fields match or are null. You order by match quality. I rank a year match highest, then season then brand using some math where I use MySQL's feature to evaluate boolean expressions to 1 f0r TRUE and 0 for FALSE. So a year macth with no brand is better than a brand match with no year. Then take the first record, i.e. the best match. I expect a value of 5% to be stored as 0.5? Else you would have to change the formula. At last, if no records match at all, I multiply the price with 1, thus keeping the price.

```
select 
  id,
  season_id,
  year,
  price * 
  coalesce
  (
    (
      select 1 - s.value
      from sales s
      where coalesce(s.season_id, p.season_id) = p.season_id
      and coalesce(s.year, p.year) = p.year
      and coalesce(s.brand_id, p.brand_id) = p.brand_id
      order by
        (s.year is not null) * 4 + 
        (s.season_id is not null) * 2 + 
        (s.brand_id is not null) * 1 desc
      limit 1
    ), 1
  ) as calc_price
from products p;
```